# How do I change the size of a Div based on the screen size with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, resize

What is wrong in my jquery? I would like to make my div bigger depending on screen size and there is plenty of good examples, but still no success.

```
.picLeft {
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 130px !important;-------> I need to change this
    height: 130px;-------> I need to change this
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px !important;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
}

**EDIT TWO DIVS LIKE THAT**
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;
console.log("height------->" +height);
console.log("width-------->" +width);
// <div class="ui-block-a picLeft" id="leftDiv">
//$("#leftDiv").css("width","300 !important"); NOT working
$(".picLeft").css("width","300 !important"); //NOT Working
```

---

```
<div class="ui-grid-a"   style="background-color:black">
    <div class="ui-block-a picLeft" id="leftDiv">
    <img src="images/nk100x100.jpg" data-theme="c"
                id="pictureId" />
</div>
    <div class="ui-block-b picRight">
        <img src="images/th100x100.jpg" data-theme="c" id="pictureId2"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!
Sami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression in your css file something like the example below too:

```
width: expression((document.body.clientWidth - 300)  + "px") !important;
```

Thought it might be useful. You can also do conditional ones like this too:

```
width: expression( document.body.clientWidth > 1000 ? "1000px" : "99%" );
```

I know this isn't what you asked but others have already given good examples; this is just an alternative.

Comment: That is working, Thank you all! I wonder why js-solution is not working? Btw, how can I set height to be always as big what weight is?

Comment: No problem. Maybe post the css you used for others to benefit from. Your comment looks like a mistype. Please clarify what you meant?

Comment: oh sorry :) NOT weight. I would like to get height to be as big as width, is it possible just in CSS? Your code was correct, I just added it like you wrote it.

Comment: Sure. Just set the css `height` and `width` to the same expression using `document.body.clientHeight` and `document.body.clientWidth` as you need. You would need to set each separately still though as far as I know.

Comment: I mean if width = 200px, height should be 200px as well. Btw I tried this and this is not working: width: expression(((document.body.clientWidth/2) -100)  + "px") !important; Is it possible to divide like that, because I have two divs, so I need to divide clientWidth first.

Comment: Yes that should be possible. However, if you're wanting 2 divs to fill the screen, maybe you should use % widths with margins and padding?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".picLeft").css("width","300px !important"); //Added "px"
```

Comment: Not working in my case, thanks and sorry. Both divs are exactly same size 130px X 130px. I think that it should work like that, but no :( $(document).ready(function(){
 
 console.log("---init---"); 
});
$(".picLeft").css("width","300px !important");

Answer (score 2):

you have missed `px`:

```
$(".picLeft").css("width","300px !important");
```

I suggest to use percentage values or CSS3 Media Queries for doing this.

Comment: what differs your answer towards mine?

Comment: Oh we answered at the same time :)... Well, i upvote your answer

Comment: Not working :( Div is still the same size.                          $(".picLeft").css("width","300px !important");

Comment: @Sami there is no need to use jQuery, you can use percentage values or css3 media queries.

Comment: @Raminson I have to get familiar with that or have you got any ready solution for that. I hate css+jquery combination, I have every time some problems with it :(

Comment: @Sami by using Media Queries there is no need to use jQuery, please check this http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/media-queries/ and http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$(window).resize(function()
{
    $('#display').css('width', ($(this).width() - 100) + 'px');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qJCc9/

Comment: It is working in fiddle, but I can't get it working in my app? IN console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in line }); $(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).resize(function()
   {
       $('#leftDiv').css('width', ($(this).width() - 100) + 'px !important');
   });​
 //changeDivSize();
 });

Comment: @Sami Remove `!important` and it should work. .css(...) applies the style inline and therefore it will take precedence. http://jsfiddle.net/qJCc9/16/

Comment: Nope :( I think that maybe it is still because of jquery mobile grids. It is working in Fiddle, but when I just insert your code between <script></script> nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
 var width = jQuery(window).width();       
 jQuery('div.picLeft').css('width':width); 
 jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        var width = jQuery(window).width();  
        jQuery('div.picLeft').css('width':width);
    });
```

Comment: No working, same final result. I wonder if there is something about Jquery and that another class ui-block-a or the mother div?

Comment: Is not working on re size? Sorry for the first time I did't calculate the width. I've added now. Please try again. Any error thrown?

Comment: It is not working in any case :( The two divs are always the same size. I tried your solution like this:                                                                  width ="300px !important";
  jQuery('div.picLeft').css('width':width); 
  jQuery(window).resize(function() {
         var width = jQuery(window).width();  
         jQuery('div.picLeft').css('width':width);});